# PHP numbers, hide largenumbers

Tags: php, numbers

Hi i have a one question.

I get this numbers in result: 1.1115628363

I want to show the first three numbers example: 1.11

But i dont know how to do this. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
$number = 1.1115628363;
$formated_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php) function for that.

Try below code :

```
$test = 1.1115628363;
echo substr($test, 0, 4);
```

Comment: but its not a string, there are much better integer based functions

Comment: @Dagon thats why i have use statement " YOU CAN" i haven't say "YOU MUST" every dev have different choice